# Specifying Dir on a new cmd

Tags: python, subprocess

A new window gets opened but the path is  not specified

```
      subprocess.Popen('start cmd  cd C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Tabula/tabula/tabula.exe', shell=True)
```

I want to run the tabula.exe file in a new cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you just want to change directory:

```
import os
os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k cd C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Tabula/tabula")
```

or this to run the exe:

```
import os
os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Tabula/tabula/tabula.exe")
```

Comment: I tried this but it opens the working directory in which spyder is set to rather then the path specified

Comment: This worked                                                    
  os.chdir('D:\\ChromeDownloads\\tabula')
 tabula_path = os.system('"start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k D:\\ChromeDownloads\\tabula\\tabula.exe"')

Answer (score 0):

with `Popen`, you can specify the directory in the `cwd` parameter

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

> If cwd is not None, the function changes the working directory to cwd before executing the child. cwd can be a str and path-like object. In particular, the function looks for executable (or for the first item in args) relative to cwd if the executable path is a relative path.

Comment: when I run this code     'subprocess.Popen('start cmd', shell=True,cwd=r'C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Tabula/tabula/tabula.exe')' I get the error NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid where if i delete tabula.exe a new cmd opens and then i can type in tabula.exe and then the application opens

Comment: Try something like this:
subprocess.Popen('start cmd C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Tabula/tabula/tabula.exe', shell=True,cwd=r'C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Tabula/tabula')

Comment: No still it goes only to the path specified i have to type in tabula.exe for the application to run